# Genymotion on Android Studio install issue

Tags: android-studio, genymotion

I have installed Android Studio and Genymotion, put a virtual device in Genymotion, installed the plugin of Genymotion on Android Studio, and the AS has created an icon in the second line of menu icons, called 'Genymotion Device Manager'. If I click that, Genymotion will open that virtual phone. However, if I press play, to deploy application, it does not find Genymotion and I have to choose the default emulator.

I have now checked and made the path to the sdk from Genymotion, and refreshed. However, unfortunately when I deploy an application, it still does not give me an option to run it through Genymotion and I am still left only with the option of deploying through the Android Studio emulator, which works but is limited.

---EDIT---

Using Windows 8.

Tried running Genymotion and deploying the app once it was open. Got he error message:

"pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.delta.bartalk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]"

I downloaded/installed the latest of everything, so I am not sure why that would happen but I feel I am getting somewhere.

------EDIT-----

The above 'older sdk' made me realise the phone I uploaded into the Genymotion to try it out is an older phone and on closer inspection was for an older version of AS, thus the sdk was too old. Works with different phone uploaded.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could write which platform you're on; Windows, OSX or Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually works for me.

Have you tried opening the genymotion app first then you can choose the running emulator?

Comment: I hadn't. I now have and it didn't work, it gave the error:

"pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.delta.bartalk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]"